# Should I create individual Apps in Mobile Studio?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

I need to create an app within Mobile Studio to be able to send push notifications within MC (Mobile Studio > Admin > Apps).

Should I create one app for both Android and iOS or should I create one for each platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create just one App in the Admin section of Mobile Push, in which your Apps from both operating systems (Android and iOS) will have the same ApplicationID in Marketing Cloud.